# looping through subviews or a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

What am I doing wrong? The views are set up in IB. There are 3 subviews of answersView. Each are UITextViews. But I get an answer that I can't set text on a UIView. Thanks in advance.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<[[[self answersView]subviews]count]; i++) 
{
    UITextView *currentText = (UITextView *)[[self answersView] viewWithTag:i];
    NSString *answer = [[self answersArray] objectAtIndex:i];
    [currentText setText:answer];
}
```

The error is:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f56330'

Okay I've updated the code

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<[[[self answersView]subviews]count]; i++) 
{
    UITextView *currentText = (UITextView *)[[self answersView] viewWithTag:i+1];
    if ([currentText isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        NSString *answer = [[self answersArray] objectAtIndex:i];
        [currentText setText:answer];
        NSLog(@" tag %d",i + 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: May i know how your accepted answer solve the problem? You have used my solution and accepted some other answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a `-1` in your for loop so you don't go out of bounds. Also, you need to check that the sub view is a textfield object, or else you're going to be setting text on some other kind of view.

**Code:**

```
for (int i=0; i<[[[self answersView]subviews]count]-1; i++) {
    if ([[[self answersView] viewWithTag:i] isKindOfClass:@"UITextView") {
        UITextView *currentText = (UITextView *)[[self answersView] viewWithTag:i];
        NSString *answer = [[self answersArray] objectAtIndex:i];
        [currentText setText:answer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there,
I think that your code is pretty prone to errors because it relies upon the fact that the views are always going to have a tag number set. You could do two things in my opinion:

1) Check prior to calling setText that currentText is a valid UITextView doing something like this:

```
if ([currentText isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
{
   ...
   [currentText setText:answer];
   ...
}
```

2) What I actually think it is better, loop through the subviews this way:

```
for (UITextView* currentText in [[self answersView]subViews])
{
   ...
   [currentText setText:answer];
   ...
}
```

Comment: Version 2 didn't work for me. I'd like to use a for loop, though. If you use a for loop, will they be in tag order? They need to be in order so that the correct text goes to the correct textView.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag value greater than 0. Loop from 1 to array count.

The super view will have the default tag value as 0. Because of that only you are getting such an error.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. However, with the following code I don't get tag 3, and if I do something to change that it goes out of bounds, although I know for certain that there are 3 UITextViews in the view and nothing else. int i;
 for (i=1; i<[[[self answersView]subviews]count]; i++) 
 {
  UITextView *currentText = (UITextView *)[[self answersView] viewWithTag:i];
  NSString *answer = [[self answersArray] objectAtIndex:i];
  [currentText setText:answer];
  NSLog(@" tag %d",i);
 }

Comment: for (i=1; i<[[[self answersView]subviews]count]+1; i++)